# Link all buttons to a class in CSS?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap and I want to link all button elements to have the same CSS properties as the  `btn` and `btn-primary` classes.

How can this be achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to write CSS values for the button element itself, you will need to use JavaScript to apply a class on each button element:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('button')].forEach(button => {
button.classList.add("btn-primary");
button.classList.add("btn");
})
```

```css
.btn, .btn-primary {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<button>test</button>
<button>test2</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the button element itself and copy the CSS properties over from the `.btn` and `.btn-primary`.

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #858796;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0.35rem;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #075b8f;
  border-color: #075b8f;
}

button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0773b1;
  border-color: #0773b1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus, button.focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(105, 136, 228, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(105, 136, 228, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```